# Не работает функция imagecreatefromgif

Tags: php, функции

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему у меня не работают функции `imagecreatefrom`. Библиотеки `php_exif.dll`, `php_mbstring.dll` я подключила.

Answer (score 1):

exif и mbstring тут вообще никаким боком. Первое — это работа с метаданными картинок (судя по имени), а второе — работа с многобайтными текстовыми кодировками. Тебе gd нужно включить.